# IDE with rich content assist for Salesforce Apex

Tags: ide

I work with **Salesforce Apex**.

We use the *developer console* or *VSCode* for development.

The developer console supports compilation issue prompting while development though that is slow and content assists to quickly complete development.

*VSCode* does not have such a thing, we need to deploy the code in org to check if there is any compilation issue.

The content assist is there in *VSCode* but it suggests every available keyword in the current file. It can be optimized to suggest a member of the particular object we are working on.

Earlier Eclipse used to support ForceCode, but I believe now that support is also taken down.

Is there any plugin for *VSCode* or *Chrome* which can show the compilation issues as soon as possible as Eclipse does for Java?

If we can have a plugin on *VSCode* which can compile on available local fetched components so we will have fewer compilation issues after saving on Org and intelligently suggest autocomplete.

Though Salesforce is the biggest Cloud CRM but still lacks such basic stuff.

If someone is working on that thing I would be happy to support.

Such a thing will save millions of hours of developer waiting for compilation complete.